# Username check from mysql Database during send a message using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a simple php code to send mail to registered members which are in mysql database. Before the action form is processed i need to check if the receiver field contains a valid username from the user table or not. If not then it will show a ajax alert on the page that 'not a valid user' the compose message form is -

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");
include("includes/usermenu.php");
include("includes/connection.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
    $ret_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($fetch_user = mysql_fetch_array($ret_user)){
            $username = $fetch_user['username'];
            }
            $ret_count = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE receiver = '$username' and readstatus = '0'  ORDER BY timesend") or die(mysql_error());
        $msgcount = 0;
            while($countmsg = mysql_fetch_array($ret_count))
            { $msgcount++;
            }
?>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/check_user.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("#username").autocomplete("includes/source.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
</script>

<div id='slidemenu'>

<ul>
   <li><a href='compose.php'><span>Compose</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='mailbox.php'><span>Inbox</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='unread.php'><span>Unread <strong>(<?php echo $msgcount; ?>)</strong></span></a></li>
   <li><a href='outbox.php'><span>Outbox</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="msgbox" align="right">
            <div style="height:25px; text-align:center; margin-top: 20px;" >   <font style="color:yellow;font-size:18px;font-family:'Orienta', sans-serif; font-size: 12px;" id="W"></font> 
                                  <div  id="HIDDEN" style="display: none;"> </div>
            </div>
    <table>
    <form action="includes/savemsg.php" method="post">
                <tr><td><label for="rec">Recievers ID</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1"/><br /><br /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subject" tabindex="2"/><br /><br /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="msg">Message</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="3" tabindex="3"></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" onClick="check_user();"/></td></tr>

    </form>
    </table>









</div>



<?php
}
else    header("location: login.php");
include("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

and action php file is -

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $rec_id = $_POST['username'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $ret_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($fetch_user = mysql_fetch_array($ret_user)){
            $username = $fetch_user['username'];
            }


    $send_msg = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO inbox VALUES(DEFAULT,'$username','$rec_id','$subject','$message',now(),now(),'0')") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
    <script>
        alert("Message send");
    </script>   
    <?php
 header ("location: ../mailbox.php")    

?>
```

What will be the ajax code to check it.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: except the alert message all other things are alright.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the security hole.

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or PDO

Comment: Try to write the ajax call on your own, take a look at the documentation => http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Then you can post your specific questions.